# How do you read the whole of a file in python as a single line instead of line by line?

Tags: python, file

Let us say I wanted to read a whole file at once instead of going through it line by line (let's say for example to speed up retrieval of the times 'i' occurs in the file). How would I go about reading it as a whole instead of the lines in which it is written?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("file.ext", 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

As others have mentioned, you can find an [official Python tutorial for Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) which explains this. You can also see the [Methods of File Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) section, which explains the use of `f.read(size)` and `f.readline()` and the difference between between them.

Comment: Someone linked the docs to where this is specified, I knew the thing you stated, nowhere is it specified that that is specifically what it does. In fact I asked because none of my search results answered the question. Thank you

Comment: @BrechtCorbeel it is specified here what it specifically does: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects _To read a file’s contents, call f.read(size), which reads some quantity of data and returns it as a string (in text mode) or bytes object (in binary mode). size is an optional numeric argument. When size is omitted or negative, the entire contents of the file will be read and returned_